# Android browser crashes on Ajax calls, when viewport meta tag is defined

Tags: html, android, ajax, webkit, viewport

I am building a web app, which is intended to run on the Android browser.

When I have a webpage that contains any kind of viewport meta tag, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400"/>
```

My webpage crashes on ajax calls. It happens when using the emulator, the actual browser on my nexus one, and on a droid (all running Android 2.1).

Without the meta tag, the ajax calls run as they should.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the exception from the logcat?

Comment: Could you post or host a sample page that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's recommended these days that you set content="width=device-width" and style the page with CSS to look at least tolerable. Otherwise you get a ridiculously zoomed-in page on the iPad.

Of course, never mind if you already have a way of dealing with that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the below meta tag.

I have successfully used both these meta tags and AJAX calls did work for me on the Nexus One.

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```